# SQL Server Creating Certificate from file failed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to implement SQL server mirroring scenario using self signed certificate and without domain environment but with no luck.

Firstly, I did these commands,

```
CREATE master key Encryption by password = 'Aa123456';
Create certificate MirrorCert with subject = 'SQLMirror certificate'
Create endpoint endpoint_mirroring state = started as tcp(listener_port = 7024, listener_ip = all) for database_mirroring (authentication = certificate MirrorCert, encryption = disabled, role = all);
Backup certificate MirrorCert to file = 'c:\Backup\MirrorCert.cer';
```

but on the principle server when trying to import above mentioned certificate after copying it to some location there using this command:

```
CREATE CERTIFICATE SQL_Mirror_Cert AUTHORIZATION Mirror_user FROM FILE = '‪C:\Backup\MirrorCert.cer'
```

I get this error:

```
The certificate, asymmetric key, or private key file is not valid or does not exist; or you do not have permissions for it.
```

I do not know what error was made by me, any help will be appreciated.

Update:
I have tried many things with no luck except [this link](https://www.dcac.com/blog/exchanging-sql-certificates-with-different-service-accounts-can-be-tricky) which talks about NTFS permissions of the produced certificate from SQL server and I do not know how to set or reset the certificate permission (I tried certificate file traditional security permission with no effect).

Comment: What type of user is `Mirror_user`? Does the file exist on the `Principle Server`? Are you logged on as a `sysadmin` on the `Principle Server`?

Comment: Mirror user is sysadmin, the certificate copied to principle server, yes I am using sysadmin account on principle server. I am using mixed mode with built in administrator account which is sysadmin

Comment: So, did you find a solution?